# Magento 1.9.4.3 - Separate the same products in the cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, virtual-products

I would like to separate the same virtual products in the cart that are added several times by different product pages.
Consequently I would like the subtotal to be calculated based on this separation.

Of course I would like to do this without risking duplicating the products in the database once I save the order in this way.

How can I do?
Thanks